# Click on picture using Cypress

Tags: testing, cypress

[image: CLick on favorite button]

How can I click on the favourite button by using Cypress? I have tried:

```js
cy.contains('img', {matchCase: false}).click({force: true}); 
cy.get('[alt="Image"]').click();
cy.get('[src="Images/outline_star_border_black_18dp.png"]').click({force: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it by getting the toolbar and drilling into it,

```
cy.get('.topbar')  // get the containing toolbar
  .children()      // all the children with it
  .eq(1)           // take the second one
  .find('img')     // all the icons
  .eq(0)           // take the first one (NOTE they are reverse order to display)
  .click()
```

Or use `.find()` and a partial match the source string to search within the toolbar

```
cy.get('.topbar')  // get the containing toolbar
  .find('img[src*="outline_star"]')     // *= gives a partial match on src
  .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, something like this would help. First find element by *cy.xpath()* or *cy.get()* and then filter more like elements having **src** tag and then if **src** having url containing outline_star_border_black, then it  click on element simple :)

```
const elem= cy.xpath('div[class="main"]>div:nth-child(2)>div>
img:nth-child(1)').should('have.attr', 'src')

if (elem.should('contain', 'outline_star_border_black')) {
elem.click()
}
```

Comment: const elem= cy.get('div[class="col-lg-2 col-md-2"]').should('alt="Image", Images/outline_star_border_black_18dp.png')
 if (elem.should('contain', 'outline_star_border_black')) {
 elem.click()
 }

Comment: We cant use parameters of our choices in .should() like you did.
Read this https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Syntax

Comment: write this const elem= cy.get('div[class="col-lg-2 col-md-2"]>img').should('have.attr', 'alt')
if you want to assert on "alt" attribute

Comment: write this const elem= cy.get('div[class="col-lg-2 col-md-2"]>img').should('have.attr', 'alt')
if you want to assert on "alt" attribute
But the issue is alt='image are more than one underneath div tag and the class name is also not looking very unique . Try with this: cy.get('.topbar').children().eq(1).find('img').eq(0).click()